# Clicking on an empty area of the table qtableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

QTableWidget has data. When I click on a cell, I make the button active. How to do this when I click outside the table, or outside the cell, on an empty area of the table so that the button is inactive again

```
def delete_param():
    ui.toolButton_4.setEnabled(True)

ui.tableWidget.itemSelectionChanged.connect(delete_param)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to subclass `QTableWidget` and override `focusOutEvent()` where you can call `clearSelection()` method:

```
class MyTableWidget(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def focusOutEvent(self):
        self.clearSelection()
```

[source](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/48549-QTableWidget-Unselect-cell-onClick-outside-of-control)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what it's about, but I'll answer just by looking at the title.

```
class MyTableWidget(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUI()

    def setupUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(800, 200, 300, 300)

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self)
        self.tableWidget.resize(290, 290)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem(""))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, QTableWidgetItem(""))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 0, QTableWidgetItem(""))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 1, QTableWidgetItem(""))

        self.tableWidget.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
        
    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if(event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Type.MouseButtonPress and
        event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton and
        self.tableWidget.itemAt(event.pos()) is None and
        source is self.tableWidget.viewport()):
            print('Global Pos:', event.globalPos())
        return super(MyTableWidget, self).eventFilter(source, event)
```

This works when you click `TableWidget`, which has empty area.